# How to test odoo modules

Tags: odoo

I developed an odoo module, I want to test it, I alreay read this topic [testing odoo module](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/testing.html), but there is no enought details about this.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are trying to test your module but the link you provide is for creating python test cases. I think this might [help](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html) you.